# Extend a measure to a Radon measure

Tags: measure-theory, geometric-measure-theory

A Radon measure $\mu:\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{R}^n)\to [0,\infty]$ is an outer measure such that

1. Each Borel set $E\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R^n})$ is $\mu$-measurable;
2. For every $F\subset \mathbb{R}^n$, there exists $E\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R^n})$ such that $\mu(E)=\mu(F)$;
3. $\mu(K)<\infty$ if $K$ is compact.

Now let $\mu$ be a Radon measure, and let $u:\mathbb{R^n}\to \mathbb [0,\infty)$ be $\mu$-measurable. Define the set function $u\mu:\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R^n}) \to [0,\infty]$ by
$$u\mu(E)=\int_E ud \mu.$$ Then $u\mu$ is a Borel measure defined on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R^n})$.

I know that we can extend $u\mu$ to be an outer measure. My question is, is it possible to extend it to be a Radon measure?

Comment: If $u$ is locally integrable, for sure, otherwise no.

Comment: @OliverDiaz Thanks! Do you know how to check the second condition for $u\mu$ given $u$ is locally integrable?

Comment: (1) is obvious; condition 3. is clear by local integrability.  Notice that $u \mu$ (in your notation) is $\sigma$-finite. Then it is enough to assume that $mu$ is actually integrable. There is a well know result that says that finite measures on the Borel space $\mathbb{R^d},\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is outer-regular (see the construction of Lebesgue measure on Cohn's measure theory for instance, or Rudin's construction of integration in locally compact Hausdorff spaces) That will prove 2.